# AWS: Iot to Kinesis

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, aws-iot

The IoT rules engine provides a direct connection to push IoT events onto Kinesis steams -- but I can't find any discussion regarding the conversion of IoT events into Kinesis records...

My events look like this:
{"time_stamp" : "2012:07:15:18:24:09:890:00","customer_id" : "000001","device_id" : "000001"}

While the AWS documentation here shows a sample Kinesis record:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis-example-upload-deployment-pkg.html

I find it difficult to believe anyone would have their devices send that much info over the wire -- so a conversion must take place...what is the preferred method of converting device events into Kinesis records?  It does not seem
to happen automatically...

Comment: NO LOVE.
Am I the only one attempting to move
records from IOT to Kinesis to Lambda?